# Issue with pulling variable from exponential as exponent

Tags: complex-numbers

So My understanding is that $$e^{2x} =(e^{x})^2 $$

but why is the following statement incorrect $$e^{i 2 \pi \theta} = (e^{i 2 \pi})^{\theta} = 1 $$

It cannot possibly be true, a counter example, take $\theta = 1/2$

then$$e^{i 2 \pi \theta} = e^{i \pi} = -1 \not=1$$

so why can I not just pull the variable as an exponent ?

Comment: The formula $(e^{a})^b = e^{ab}$ is not valid when $a$ is not real, unless $b$ is an integer.

Comment: is there a proof for this theorem I can look up ?

Comment: A proof that it is no more valid? A counterexample like yours suffices.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Is it actually valid, if $b$ is an integer ?

Comment: Yes, because exponential is a group morphism from $(\mathbb{C},+)$ to $(\mathbb{C}^*,\times)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first claim is incorrect. Firstly, the equation $e^{i\theta} = \cos{\theta} + i\sin{\theta}$ truly originates from $i\theta = \ln\big({\cos{\theta} + i\sin{\theta}}\big)$. This statement itself is not correct for all values of $\theta$ because the complex logarithm may have infinitely many outputs (these are grouped under branches). Unless, you look at a finite, single branch there is no saying what $\big({e^{i2\pi}}\big)^\theta = 1^{\theta}$ equals.

Secondly, think of the real function $y = e^x; D:(-\infty, \infty) \to R: (0, \infty)$. Its inverse would be $y = \ln(x); D:(0, \infty) \to R: (-\infty, \infty)$. See that the range are swapped with the domain (and vice-versa). If this inversing were done in the complex world, with $e^{i\theta}$, what complex range would "swap" to the real domain? Certain values would have to be ommitted.

Hence, under $\mathbb{C}$, $\big({e^{i2\pi}}\big)^\theta = 1^{\theta}$ may have $1$ real solution but many more complex ones. Additionally, see that with your claim $i2\pi \theta = \ln\big(\cos{2\pi} + i\sin{2\pi}\big) = 0$. Does that mean $\theta = 0$ always? But $1^\theta$ is defined for many more values of $\theta$.

---

Your last claim is incorrect because $z^\frac{1}{2} = \pm\sqrt{e^{i2\pi}} = \pm\sqrt{1} = \pm 1$.